# Magento 2: Disable default header and add custom header content

Tags: magento2, layout, custom, phtml, header

I have created a custom header container and placed inside

`app/design/Foo/bar/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`

Now the content I need is showing up, but also displaying default header contents link links, welcome message, search, logo and titles.

I tried removing them by `remove="true"` in frontend default.xml, it removes my custom design as well.

Please correct me or let me know how I can use a custom header. Right way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom header, you must create a default.xml layout in design/fontend//default/Magento-Theme/layout
In this layout you can remove blocks you don't want.
The original template in Magento is in app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

To remove a block just write : 

or 
It depends on which block. Some blocks are necessary to Magento, for example because they have some important js files include. So you can not displayed them but not remove.